# How do I make all of these images the same dimension but still Bootstrap responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code that displays images and a countdown below the images. How do I make all the images the same *dimensions* but also let Bootstrap be responsive? At the same time, also making sure the countdown box below stays with the dimensions of the images? Thanks :)

```css
/* Books */

#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.description_one, .description_two, .description_three {
  color: #9B0103;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #9B0103;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description_one a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#book_column a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* End of Books */
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
      
      <!-- First Book -->
      
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1472913234l/29563587.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_one' token_id='4ce0e43b806457bbc21881748d6a50d2'>
                <div class='description_one'>
                  5:05:12
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                        

<!-- End of First Book -->

<!-- Second Book -->

  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388211242l/69571.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_two' token_id='bb8673cb597c7fc7cba7bc13d9f08a4b'>
                <div class='description_two'>
                  6:32:14
                </div> </a>
            </div>            


<!-- End of Second Book -->

<!-- Third Book -->
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1342493368l/3636.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_three' token_id='25ea7f6c20f1f185841ed88c9a9d2f2c'>
                <div class='description_three'>
                  7:12:04
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                         
<!-- End of Third Book -->
```

Comment: http://gridbyexample.com

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Is it a plugin of Bootstrap? I'm already using Bootstrap and I don't really want to rewrite all my code :)

Comment: For that your images have to be of same dimensions, or all else it would stretched or compressed. Or you could do is give an element / div tag specific width and height and add image as background.

Comment: @divy3993 What image would look good in the bg?

Comment: The same image you are placing in your `<img .../>` tag. If too many such or coming dynamically, you will need JS to do so.

Comment: @divy3993 That sounds good. Can you show me an example? :)

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can add below at the bottom of your css

```
img[id^="book_cover"]{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

The above will target all `img` elements with id that starts with `book_cover`,  example `book_cover_one`, `book_cover_two`, etc

See snippet below

```css
/* Books */

#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.description_one, .description_two, .description_three {
  color: #9B0103;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #9B0103;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description_one a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#book_column a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
img[id^="book_cover"]{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
/* End of Books */
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
      
      <!-- First Book -->
      
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1472913234l/29563587.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_one' token_id='4ce0e43b806457bbc21881748d6a50d2'>
                <div class='description_one'>
                  5:05:12
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                        

<!-- End of First Book -->

<!-- Second Book -->

  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388211242l/69571.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_two' token_id='bb8673cb597c7fc7cba7bc13d9f08a4b'>
                <div class='description_two'>
                  6:32:14
                </div> </a>
            </div>            


<!-- End of Second Book -->

<!-- Third Book -->
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item' id='book_column'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1342493368l/3636.jpg' alt='' id='book_cover_three' token_id='25ea7f6c20f1f185841ed88c9a9d2f2c'>
                <div class='description_three'>
                  7:12:04
                </div> </a>
            </div>            
                                         
<!-- End of Third Book -->
```

**Solution 2**

Instead of solution 1, this seems much more simpler

```
.img-responsive{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add one more class to yor CSS:

```
.thumb img {

    width:  100%;
    height: 300px;

}
```

This should fix your problem.